# add stylesheet to head in javascript to html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
html = `<!doctype html><title>My title</title><head></head><body><p>hello world</p></body></html>`;
html = $.parseHTML(html);
$(html).find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css/">');

console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have no clue why this isn't work. I want to add css or js programmatically to my html in js.

after that I would like to download the variable as something.html, possible?

Comment: You are opening a `link` tag and closing a `style` tag, FYI: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css"></style>`; `link` tags are self-closing `<link href="..." />`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in pure javascript:

```js
// Get the head element
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

// Create a new style node
var style = document.createElement('style');

// Set type attribute for the style node
style.type = 'text/css';

// Set the css rules
var css = '#test {color:red}';

// Append the css rules to the style node
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

// Append the style node to the head of the page
head.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<span id="test">This is a test text</span>
```

**UPDATE (Append link to body)**

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'path/to/url');
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: What if I want to append a link?

Answer (score 0):

> I have no clue why this isn't work.

`html` string is missing opening `<html>` tag. `<title>` element should be child of `<head>` element. Note, `doctype` declaration `<!doctype html>` is not opening tag of `<html>` element.

---

Include opening `<html>` tag, place `<title>` within `<head>` at `html` string. Use `DOMParser()` to create a `document`; call `.find()` chained to `$(doc.documentElement)` to select `head`  where `doc` is `document` parsed from `html` string variable with `DOMParser`.

You can then use `<a>` element with `href` set to `doc.documentElement.outerHTML`, `download` attribute set to `something.html` to save file as `text/html` with `<link>` included by calling `.click()` on `<a>` element.

Note alos, if you load `something.html` at `file:` protocol, linked stylesheet will not be loaded into document unless you specify `http:` or `https:` protocol at `href` of `<link>` element, e.g., `http://formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css`

```js
var html = `<!doctype html><html><head><title>My title</title></head><body><p>hello world</p></body></html>`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var doctype = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc.doctype);
$(doc.documentElement).find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css"></style>');
console.log(doctype + doc.documentElement.outerHTML);
$("<a>", {
    href: "data:text/html," + doctype 
          + doc.documentElement.outerHTML,
    download: "something.html"
})
.appendTo("body")[0].click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: it's present, check again.

Comment: @MariaJane _"it's present, check again."_ `<html>`tag does not appear present at string at Question

Comment: @MariaJane See updated post. Note, `doctype` declaration `<!doctype html>` is not opening tag of `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML =list+
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='//formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css'</style>";
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
$(html).find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{url}">')
```

Comment: _"any one can explain?"_ Did not cast "downvote". Note that `html` variable at Question does not include beginning `<html>` tag